# gradle build conflict on jaxrs jars

Tags: java, gradle, jax-rs, build.gradle

In my grade file, I have the below line, it works fine.

> compile "io.swagger:swagger-jersey-jaxrs:${revSwagger}"

Now I want add a few more classes from the Javax.ws.rs jar

> import javax.ws.rs.NotAuthorizedException;
>
> import javax.ws.rs.Priorities;
>
> import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
>
> import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;

with the line in the gradle file

> compile group: 'javax.ws.rs', name: 'javax.ws.rs-api', version: '2.0'

My code compiles, but the services don't work any more.

How to solve the conflicts? Thanks.

Comment: _"but the services don't work any more"_ - What does "don't work" mean?

Comment: service won't start, it gives error when compiles with Javax implementation instead of the io.swagger implementation.